# How do I parse a MIME message from a HttpResponseMessage in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mime

After successfully sending a status inquiry...

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var mime = new MultipartFormDataContent("myBoundary");

    var attachment = new StringContent(envelope);
    // add headers to attachment
    
    mime.Add(attachment);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("/endpoint", mime);
}
```

... I recieve the following response.

```
Content --MIME-Multipart-Boundary
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Id: RootPart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <xres:Transport>
            <xres:TransportBody>
                <xres:Package>
                    <xcpt:Data>
                        <xcpt:Base64CharSequence>
                            <inc:Include href="cid:efcd94e7-9acc-4f5a-bfe9-2bf592b591c6" />
                        </xcpt:Base64CharSequence>
                    </xcpt:Data>
                </xres:Package>
            </xres:TransportBody>
        </xres:Transport>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
--MIME-Multipart-Boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 9999
Content-Id: efcd94e7-9acc-4f5a-bfe9-2bf592b591c6
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

For the sake of simplicity, this sentence is used here instead of the actual binary data
--MIME-Multipart-Boundary--
```

The `<xres:TransportBody>...</xres:TransportBody>` contains n packages. Each package contains a **cid** (*content-id*), which references the related MIME attachment with the same cid.

After some time I came along [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit), which hopefully relieves me from my suffering. Anyways, no matter how promising [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) looks to me, I can't parse the MIME message correctly. The `multipart` variable **always** has a count of zero elements.

```cs
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var contentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);

var contentType = ContentType.Parse(response.Content.Headers.ContentType!.MediaType);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(contentBytes, false))
{
    var multipart = MimeEntity.Load(contentType, ms) as Multipart;

    // Nothing to iterate, so it skips the foreach loop
    foreach (var attachment in multipart.OfType<MimePart>())
    {
        using (var attachmentMs = new MemoryStream())
        {
            attachment.Content.DecodeTo(attachmentMs);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** Does anybody knows how I could parse the above MIME message using [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)?

I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

---

**Update:**

Apparently, `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` returns a slightly different result compared to the actual response object. The response object has the correct header `Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIME-Multipart-Boundary`.

So it seems as if important information is being lost in the parsing process of the response object. I've already tried some different approaches, but all resulted in the same "error".

```
// Approach 1
await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

// Approach 2
var parsedResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(parsedResponse);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());

// Approach 3
var parsedResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(parsedResponse);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
```

Am I doing something wrong - How do I get the actual response data?

---

**Update:**

As [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) mentioned in the comments...

> Using String methods or Encoding methods on binary data will corrupt the data.

Therefore I came up with the following approach, which now takes in all 11137 bytes of the response - So, no more missing information (hopefully).

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
{
    ms.Position = 0;

    // Could get the correct MediaType here: multipart/related
    var contentType = ContentType.Parse(response.Content.Headers.ContentType!.MediaType);

    // Could not get the correct boundary. Boundary is null here
    var multipart = MimeEntity.Load(contentType, ms) as Multipart;
    
    // Only thing left, is to get the boundary automatically
    contentType.Boundary = "MIME-Multipart-Boundary";

    // Nothing to iterate, so it skips the foreach loop
    foreach (var attachment in multipart.OfType<MimePart>())
    {
        using (var attachmentMs = new MemoryStream())
        {
            attachment.Content.DecodeTo(attachmentMs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The multipart is on a new line that starts with two dashes.  Sample has nothing below the two dashes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true  Octet-stream is binary.  So you cannot use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content) which will corrupt binary data.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng First of all, thanks for your comment. I've also wondered why my response looked a bit different as descriped in the interface description of the API I am calling. Anyways, I think I might have found the error, but I have no clue how I could fix it. Apparently, some information is lost after parsing the response with `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Comment: Would be nice if you can add an actual response to the question, in full. Then people can just copy paste it and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Evk That would be a huge pain in the a**, since I only saw this problem in the debugger. Anyways I might have found a different error, but I have to take a deeper look into this - I will try my best to add as many informations as possible.

Comment: Using String methods or Encoding methods on binary data will corrupt the data.

Comment: @jdweng That makes totally sense, but what should I use instead. The `response.Content` does not allow any other methods, or?

Comment: @jdweng My bad, just found out that `response.Content` also has the method `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`. Throughout that I can now read the complete response using a MemoryStream. Anyways I somehow can't get the boundary right...

Comment: After filling MS remember to set position to zero before reading.  Where are you searching for the two dashes at start of line?

Comment: Use Array.Find() to locate dashes.

Comment: @jdweng The position is now set to zero (Edited my question). Normally that should be done by MimeKit. But I asume they are searching for the header `Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIME-Multipart-Boundary`, which isn't there, since `response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` only returns the content and not the headers. Right now I am searching for a way in MimeKit to set the boundary manually

Comment: The mime is the body of a request/response and contains the mime headers  Do not get the HTTP Headers confused with the mime headers in the body.  A request/response has three parts 1) URL (request only) 2) HTTP Headers 3) Body

Comment: @jdweng You're absolutely right. I know that there is a difference, anyways not every MIME header was copied to the `Multipart`, which resulted in the missing boundary. I don't know how and I might have messed up anywhere... **Anyways**, I found the solution. `ContentType` is a MimeKit class, which allows me to specify the boundary, see edited question. I have successfully iterated through the attachments after setting the property with the correct value. **Thanks for your huge help! :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
{
    // Set the position of the memory stream to zero
    ms.Position = 0;

    // Set the MediaType (multipart/related)
    var contentType = ContentType.Parse(response.Content.Headers.ContentType!.MediaType);

    // Set the boundary of the ContentType
    contentType.Boundary = "MIME-Multipart-Boundary";

    var multipart = MimeEntity.Load(contentType, ms) as Multipart;

    foreach (var attachment in multipart.OfType<MimePart>())
    {
        using (var attachmentMs = new MemoryStream())
        {
            attachment.Content.DecodeTo(attachmentMs);
        }
    }
}
```